# How to not display label from password field in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Currently, I work the registratio form of my forum...

When I use `{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword }}` in twig view I get:

```
<div>
    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first" class="required">First</label>
    <input id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][first]" required="required" type="password">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second" class="required">Second</label>
    <input id="fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_second" name="fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][second]" required="required" type="password">
</div>
```

RegistrationFormType.php

```
class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $class;

    /**
     * @param string $class The User class name
     */
    public function __construct($class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                //'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
                //'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => $this->class,
            'intention'  => 'registration',
        ));
    }

    // BC for SF < 2.7
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $this->configureOptions($resolver);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'bissap_user_registration';
    }
}
```

Usualy, when i use only `form_widget`, label is not display but with this form builder configuration label still in the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, `password` field is a combinaison of two fields : `first` and `second`

> form_widget password  = 2 x ( form_row input )

**Instead of code with**

```
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword }}
```

**Just change by**

```
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second }}
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove label :

```
$builder
            ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('username', null, array('label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
            ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
                'type' => 'password',
                'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
                //'first_options' => array('label' => false),
                //'second_options' => array('label' => false),
                'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
            ))
        ;
```

Just have to pass `array('label' => false)` in your form builder add.

Comment: my question is "How to not display label?"